# Specific Layout in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a menu in Kivy but I am having a few issues with layouts. I've tried `GridLayout` and `FloatLayout` but I want to combine their functionality so that I can center the menu on screen.

```
------------------------------------------
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                Play Game               |
|                                        |
|                 Scores                 |
|                                        |
|                 About                  |
|                                        |
|                                        |
------------------------------------------
```

For some reason, I can not space my buttons and use position hints to place the menu in the center of the screen. Does anyone have any ideas about what I can do to solve this issue?

```
<Button>:
    font_name: 'fonts/Roboto.ttf'
    font_size: 15
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.1

<MainMenu>
    rows: 3
    cols: 1

    Button:
        text: 'Play Game'

    Button:
        text: 'Scores'

    Button:
        text: 'About'
```

Comment: did you try a `BoxLayout` with `orientation: vertical` around the buttons?

Comment: Yes, but I can't center it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try surrounding the buttons in a layout with padding widgets, which are empty widgets that just take some space:

```
<MainMenu>:

  BoxLayout:

    Widget:
      # empty spacer widget

    BoxLayout:
      orientation: "vertical"

      Button:
        text: 'Play Game'

      Button:
        text: 'Scores'

      Button:
        text: 'About'

    Widget:
      # empty spacer widget
```

Comment: This seems to create the menu in the corner. How can I bring it to the center of the screen?

Comment: hmm... can't see that here http://i.imgur.com/ZLFPnuT.png . Maybe you have something else in the layout that's bugging it. The layout in the answer works though.

Answer (score 1):

```
<MainMenu>:

    FloatLayout:
        size: root.size

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
            spacing: 20

            rows: 3
            cols: 1

            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

            Button:
                text: 'Play Game'

            Button:
                text: 'Scores'

            Button:
                text: 'About'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use padding

```
<Button>:
    font_name: 'fonts/Roboto.ttf'
    font_size: 15
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.1

<MainMenu>
    rows: 3
    cols: 1
    padding:  root.size[0] * 0.7 ,root.size[1] * 0.7,root.size[0] * 0.7,root.size[1] * 0.7  # 0.7 is percentage of width or height of layout [padding_left, padding_top, padding_right, padding_bottom ]

    Button:
        text: 'Play Game'

    Button:
        text: 'Scores'

    Button:
        text: 'About'
```

Comment: it depend on how you implement MainMenu